# how to load from github

Tags: r

I am following this tutorial:
http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/2012/01/29/multiple-factor-model-fundamental-data/

When I run the first script I get a multitude of errors such as

Error in url("http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz", "rb") : 
  cannot open the connection

Could anyone provide guidance on how to use this?

Comment: More suitable on superuser.com?

Comment: try using `RCurl` make sure R can access the location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first few lines of the code, you see the following:

```
###############################################################################
# Load Systematic Investor Toolbox (SIT)
# http://systematicinvestor.wordpress.com/systematic-investor-toolbox/
###############################################################################
```

Follow that URL, and you will find alternative methods to load the "SIT". For me (as suggested by @RicardoSaporta) the one that popped out as most likely to work in a general manner (because of https, binary files, and so on) was the `RCurl` method. (Be sure you have RCurl installed first!)

```
###############################################################################
# Load Systematic Investor Toolbox (SIT): Requires RCurl package
############################################################################### 
require(RCurl)
sit = getURLContent('https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz', binary=TRUE, followlocation = TRUE, ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
    con = gzcon(rawConnection(sit, 'rb'))
    source(con)
close(con)
```

Use that for the first few lines and you should be able to process the rest of the code.

---

Alternatively, manually download the file from https://github.com/systematicinvestor/SIT/raw/master/sit.gz and load it with:

```
con = gzcon(file('path/to/sit.gz', 'rb')) ## Replace with actual path
    source(con)
close(con)
```

and proceed from there.

---

Beyond that, the blog post you linked to doesn't mention a critical piece of information: what packages you need to have installed and loaded. You need to install and load "xts" and "quantmod" before running the rest of the script.

```
install.packages("xts")
install.packages("quantmod")
library(xts)
library(quantmod)
```

Comment: Yeah I just ran into this problem with xts... how do I run this library?